# dynamic Button OnServerClick event not firing in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button, dynamic

I am creating a table after reading from the database. The table displays correctly. I have a button in the table that has to trigger an event but when I click the button nothing happens. This is how the button is created:

```
tableContainer.InnerHtml += "<td>" + reader["RegistrationDateTime"] + "</td>";
tableContainer.InnerHtml += "<td><button id='Button1' runat='server'   OnServerClick='Button1_OnClick' class='button' >View Details!</button></td></tr>";
```

This is the method for the event:

```
public void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Redirect("home.aspx");    
}
```

I have searched for solutions online but only found solutions for buttons that are created like this 'Button button= new Button()'. I didn't find a solution for the way I am creating my button in the code behind file table. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The server will have no knowledge of this button when created that way. It looks like you can probably solve your problem with a javascript function that does `window.location = "home.aspx";`

Comment: 1. Isn't there any other way that I can use that button for other server side events?

Comment: 2. Is there a way to create a button like this: Button bnt1 = new Button(), get the html of this button add it  to my table above?

Comment: Yes, you can use ajax or [WebMethods](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx).